# Serializing model queryset showing empty [OrderedDict()]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am building a blog app with `React` and `Django` and I am serializing model's instances saved by particular user, First I am just trying to test with `.all()`  then I am planning to filter by specific user But when I serialize queryset with Serializer like:

```
class BlogSerializerApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Blog.objects.all()
        output_serializer = BlogSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print(output_serializer.data)
        return "Testing"
```

It is showing in console:

> [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()]

and when I access it like

```
print(output_serializer)
```

Then it is showing:

```
BlogSerializer(<QuerySet [<Blog: user_1 - Blog_title>, <Blog: user_2 - second_blog_title>]>, many=True):
```

serializer.py:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['title']
```

models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} - {self.title}"
```

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to serialize queryset to show on page in `react frontend`, I will relate with specific user later.

I have tried many times by changing `CBV` serialization method by `generics.ListAPIView` instead of `viewsets.ModelViewSet` but still same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    .......
```

so it was showing empty results (no idea why, I think its deprecated)

After replaceing it with

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
```

It worked

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept error here. The `get_queryset` function is not supposed to return serialized data. It must return a `QuerySet` of model objects.

To achieve what you want you can just do:

```py
class BlogSerializerApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Blog.objects.all()
```

The Django Rest Framework will take care of serializing data.

In fact, you can even do it way more simple. Defining the view's queryset field like this:

```py
class BlogSerializerApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

Additional:
You said you will relate to current user later. You could achieve that in fact in the `get_queryset` method filtering aginst the user

```py
class BlogSerializerApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Blog.objects.filter(user_id=USER_ID)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, It is showing Blank response in `react` like :- `data: Array(2)
0: {}
1: {}` and in python console, it is showing `<QuerySet [<Blog: Blog object (1)>, <Blog: Blog object (2)>]>`

Comment: I think serializer and view is working fine But something is going wrong with sending response,

Comment: I got the solution, I was using `BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):` it was showing empty response But then I read documentation again (I never realized how I missed this) and I replaced it with `BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):` and It worked